# Sharepoint 2013 _spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage is showing wrong value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, variations

In my SP2013 environment, I have 2 variations, en-US, and fr-FR. I found an issue where now when I am on the French pages, the currentCultureName is showing `en-US` for all sites. Language code is 1033. How can this be corrected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The _spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage and currentCultureName is based on what preference is saved on the user's profile settings. The region/locale field specifically. It is not based on which label the current site is on. Best way to detect language is check the URL directly.